# Fitbit URL callback giving a response of NULL

Tags: aws-lambda, react-native, react-native-ios, aws-serverless

I'm having trouble getting a response from a callback uri and I would really appreciate any help you could give me.

I am trying to use the Fitbit API which requires you to use a callback url to get an Auth Code.

```
Workflow:
1. Go to Fitbit url to get user to allow the app access to their personal data.
2. User agrees to the conditions
3. User gets redirected to my API
4. The API returns the code from (Code is located in URL and I can access it)
5. I console.log the code out to verify it
6. API returns the code
7. I work with code then exchanging it for an access token.
```

The problem is that I don't return the code (Or anything )when I return to the app even though I can console.log it on the API. The response I get is `NULL`

Here is the URL:

```
url = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://REDIRECT_URL&scope=activity%20heartrate%20location%20nutrition%20profile%20settings%20sleep%20social%20weight&expires_in=604800";
```

I then open the URL in the `InAPPBrowser` successfully:

```
if (url !== "") {
        const canOpen = await Linking.canOpenURL(url)
        if (canOpen) {
              try {
                const isAvailable = await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()
                
                if (isAvailable) {

                  const result =InAppBrowser.open(url, {
                    // iOS Properties
                    dismissButtonStyle: 'done',
                    preferredBarTintColor: 'gray',
                    preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
                    // Android Properties
                    showTitle: true,
                    toolbarColor: '#6200EE',
                    secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
                    enableDefaultShare: true,
                  }).then((result) => {

                    console.log("Response:",JSON.stringify(result))

                    Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
                      console.log("Tests: ",url)
                      this._setTracker(url as string);
                    });
                  })
                } else Linking.openURL(url)
              } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error: ",error)
              }
            
        }
      }
```

From here the URL opens successfully.

Here is the API now which is done in Typescript on AWS serverless and Lambda

```
export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event, _context, callback) =>{
    let provider = event.path

    //prints code
    let x = event.queryStringParameters

    console.log("Code: ",x)
    
    

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "Success"
      };
      return response;
}
```

Please let me know if further detail is required?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so it turns out what I was doing was correct apart from the response should have been 301 which is a redirect response.

```
const response= {
        statusCode: 301,
        headers: {
            "location": `app://CALLBACK RESPONSE ADDRESS?type=${provider}`
        },
        body: "Boom"
    }
```